# What resolution or size of images need I to make app for all iphone?

Tags: ios, xcode, resolution

I need know waht resolution or size of images need I to make an universal app. I need all images to show correctly in iphone 4, 4s, 5, 5s. I know that need images resources with @2x in the name for see in retina, but I don't know what resolution need this pictures? Need I one image to iphone 4, the same for 4s, 5, and 5s?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a proper display in every iPhone version, the images have to different in sizes. Apple has some predefined size standard for the images and App Icons as well as the Launch Images.You can refer these official Apple link to get information about the size for Apple devices.

[Apple's Guidelines for Application Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

[Launch Images for iPhone Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html)